# Query mongodb for change in field vaule using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection and a want to track the change in value of one field in mongodb collection.

e.g. I have collection with fields name Name, Phone, address. So want to get display the result when vaule of name field gets changed. 
if Result for Name field is abc, abc, abc and xyz, xyz, xyz.... , then I want to display only first vaule of each and update that with new field.

So, final result should be--
Name:abc, New-field:vaule   -- First result abc occurance
Name:xyz, New-Field:value   -- First result of xyz occurance

Thanks!!

[Update]
Code --

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/course', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var grades = db.collection('grades');

    var cursor = grades.find({});

    var options = {  'sort' : [['grade', -1], ['student', 1]] };
    var cursor = grades.find({}, {}, options);

    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(doc == null) {
            return db.close();
        }
        console.dir(doc);
    });
});
```

Output :

```
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'UÐ [@\f¡\u0013È\u0014' },
  student: 'Amanda',
  assignment: 'hw1',
  grade: 100 }
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'UÐ [@\f¡\u0013È\u0017' },
  student: 'Amanda',
  assignment: 'exam',
  grade: 100 }
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'UÐ [@\f¡\u0013È\u000f' },
  student: 'Joe',
  assignment: 'exam',
  grade: 100 }
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'UÑÄòµQ\u000b&ûPri' },
  student: 'Joe',
  grade: 100 }
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'UÐ [@\f¡\u0013È\u0012' },
  student: 'Steve',
  assignment: 'hw3',
  grade: 100 }
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'UÐ [@\f¡\u0013È\u0013' },
  student: 'Steve',
  assignment: 'exam',
  grade: 100 }
```

Desired Output:

```
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'UÐ [@\f¡\u0013È\u0014' },
  student: 'Amanda',
  assignment: 'hw1',
  grade: 100,
  new_field: "value" }
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'UÐ [@\f¡\u0013È\u000f' },
  student: 'Joe',
  assignment: 'exam',
  grade: 100, 
  new_field: "value" }
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'UÐ [@\f¡\u0013È\u0012' },
  student: 'Steve',
  assignment: 'hw3',
  grade: 100,
  new_field: "value" }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking you are mixing backend logic with frontend one and you should show us something you did.

Comment: @Michelem I have updated with example.

Comment: Where is this new field being updated from? This update function is where you want to add the new field, not with `.find`

Comment: Yes, that I can add later. But first want to get atleast result without new filed. 

PS- I am just beginner with nodejs :(. So, apologies for silly questions.